# zipping a folder's content php, not a whole folder

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I'm looking for a solution to zip a folder's content, including all subfolders that are in the folder, **but not the main folder itself**.

I started from this function, that adds a whole folder to a zip archive

```
function addFolderToZip($dir, $zipArchive){
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {

            //Add the directory
            $zipArchive->addEmptyDir($dir);

            // Loop through all the files
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

                //If it's a folder, run the function again!
                if(!is_file($dir . $file)){
                    // Skip parent and root directories
                    if( ($file !== ".") && ($file !== "..")){
                        addFolderToZip($dir . $file . "/", $zipArchive);
                    }

                }else{
                    // Add the files
                    $zipArchive->addFile($dir . $file);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I don't see how to change the function to (maybe using a third argument ?)

```
$z = new ZipArchive();
$z->open("zips/new.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
addFolderToZip("unzipped/",$z);
$z->close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it, I have created an argument $localpath, set to "":

```
function add_folder_in_path($folder_path,$local_path,$z)
{
    $dh=opendir($folder_path);
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) 
     {
        if( ($file !== ".") && ($file !== ".."))
        {
        if (is_file($folder_path.$file))
            {

                    $z->addFile($folder_path.$file,$local_path.$file);
            }
        else
            {
                add_folder_in_path($folder_path.$file."/",$local_path.$file."/",$z);
            }
        }


     }
}
```

Here is how I call it

```
$z = new ZipArchive();
$z->open("zipped/new.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
echo "<br>";
add_folder_in_path("myzips/","",$z);
$z->close();
```